# How to swap the 0 and 1 values for each other in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe that has a column of all 0's and 1's and I am trying to switch each of the values (ie all of the 0's become 1's and all of the 1's become 0's). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace({0:1, 1:0})
```

Or faster [`numpy.logical_xor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html):

```
df = np.logical_xor(df,1).astype(int)
```

Or more faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.logical_xor(df.values,1).astype(int),columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=[10,3]))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  1  1
5  1  0  1
6  0  0  0
7  1  0  0
8  1  0  1
9  1  0  0

df = df.replace({0:1, 1:0})
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  1
3  1  1  0
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  0
6  1  1  1
7  0  1  1
8  0  1  0
9  0  1  1
```

Another solution:

```
df = (~df.astype(bool)).astype(int)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  1
3  1  1  0
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  0
6  1  1  1
7  0  1  1
8  0  1  0
9  0  1  1
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=[10000,10000]))
print (df)

In [69]: %timeit (np.logical_xor(df,1).astype(int))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.42 s per loop

In [70]: %timeit (df ^ 1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.53 s per loop

In [71]: %timeit ((~df.astype(bool)).astype(int))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.81 s per loop

In [72]: %timeit (df.replace({0:1, 1:0}))
1 loop, best of 3: 5.08 s per loop

In [73]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.logical_xor(df.values,1).astype(int), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
1 loop, best of 3: 350 ms per loop
```

Edit:
This should be faster:

```
import numexpr as ne
arr = df.values
df = pd.DataFrame(ne.evaluate('1 - arr'),columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Comment: can you do that in one go? Isn't it going to create a conflict ? Just wondering how does the algorithm work? in parallel? creating views of the original df?

Comment: @DiegoAgher - yes, one go works perfectly. I think no conflict. And how it works it is hard question for me...

Answer (score 8):

One easy way would be -

```
df[:] = 1-df.values
```

For performance, we might want to work with underlying array data, for a modified version like so -

```
a = df.values
a[:] = 1-a
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  1
3  1  1  0
4  1  0  0

In [44]: df[:] = 1-df.values

In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  1  1
```

Using `@jezrael's timings setup` with the best solution from that setup for comparison against the one proposed in this post -

```
In [46]: np.random.seed(12)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=[10000,10000]))
    ...: 

# Proposed in this post
In [47]: def swap_0_1(df):
    ...:     a = df.values
    ...:     a[:] = 1-a
    ...:     

In [48]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.logical_xor(df.values,1).astype(int), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
10 loops, best of 3: 218 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit swap_0_1(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 198 ms per loop
```

Or even better to use the negation of the boolean version of input array data -

```
In [60]: def swap_0_1_bool(df):
    ...:     a = df.values
    ...:     a[:] = ~a.astype(bool)
    ...:     

In [63]: %timeit swap_0_1_bool(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 179 ms per loop
```

Comment: Might even try `a[:] = np.logical_not(a)`, which doesn't require the `astype` reassignment

Answer (score 3):

If your dataframe consists only of 1s an 0s, you can use XOR operator `df ^ 1`

```
In [19]: import pandas as pd

In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,0,1], "b": [0,1,1]})

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  1  1

In [22]: df ^ 1
Out[22]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  0  0
```